# Using a for loop to create a dictionary. How do you stop the for loop after the dictionary is constructed?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop, pycharm

I am trying to write a script to quickly get statistics for a class I am teaching based on grades entered into an excel sheet.

I want to create a dictionary to randomly assign an alias to students actual names. So the output is `dic[alias] = student` name. I did this by using `"Student" + randint` to create the keys. It worked fine, however, every time I run the program it generates new aliases for the students. I want this to be a one and done program. I just started to learn how to program and this is way outside my wheelhouse so any help would be appreciated.

I've tried making a while loop where if `dic<= class_size` it won't loop but that gave me the same result

once the dictionary is created I want the for loop to not run.

```
for i in range(3, len(sheet["A"]) + 1):
    class_size = len(sheet["A"]) - 2
    student = "Student" + randint()
    dic[student] = sheet["A" + str(i)].value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first do is to create a list of students.

```
student_list = ['Student 1','Student 2','Student 3']
```

create an empty dictionary

```
dic = {}
```

update dictionary values by the length of the list of students

```
for student_name in student_list:
    alias = "Student" + str(randint(1,1000))
    dic.update({alias : student_name})
```

this is the whole code :

```
from random import randint

student_list = ['Arnold','Ben','Carl']
dic = {}
for student_name in student_list:
    alias = "Student" + str(randint(1,1000))
    dic.update({alias : student_name})

print(dic)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!